# What does @ do in numpy matrix manipulations?

Tags: python, numpy

I cam across this function '@' in numpy. But I am not able to figure out what it is doing or able to get documentation for it. Could someone please point me to the documentation or tell what it is doing? Code is below

```py
import numpy as np
w = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1,3]])
x1 = np.array([0,1,0,1])
s = w@x1
```

Comment: it is normal [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465